# Computing the number of elementary abelian p-subgroups of rank 2 in $GL_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{p})$

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number, and let $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ be a finite
field of order $p$. Let $GL_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{p})$ denote the general linear
group and $U_{n}$ denote the unitriangular group of $n\times n$ upper
triangular matrices with ones on the diagonal, over the finite field $%
\mathbb{F}_{p}$. In fact $U_{n}$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $GL_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{p})$ of order $p^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$. Given $n_{p^{2}}$ be the number of elementary abelian p-subgroups of rank $2$ in $U_{n}$. How can we deduce the number of elementary abelian p-subgroups of rank $2$ in the whole linear group $GL_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{p})$?.

Conversely, given $N_{p^{2}}$ be the number of elementary abelian p-subgroups of rank $2$ in $GL_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{p})$. Is there a criterion deduces the number of elementary abelian p-subgroups of rank $2$ in $U_{n}$?.

In other words, what is the relationship between $N_{p^{2}}$ and $n_{p^{2}}$?.

Any help would be appreciated so much. Thank you all.

Comment: Wouldn't $n_{p^2}$ be a better notation than $n_p^2$, which looks like the square of $n_p$?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I made a change on the notation.

Comment: I think that counting the number of conjugacy classes of such subgroups may be difficult for large $n$.  For the number of subgroups, disregarding conjugacy, it is a matter of counting the number of elements of order $p$ in $C_{G}(x)$ for each element $x$ of order $p$., and doing an elementary computation after that. However, those centralizers do not have a very transparent structure as the Jordan form of the element of order $p$ gets more complicated.

Comment: Yes, in general, it is complicated to find $N_{p^{2}}$ or $n_{p^{2}}$, so for this moment, I am not interested in this question. Here, I want to know if we assume that one of them is given, then how to find the other.